# sas : data steps versus proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

So I am starting to be a little familiar with sas, and I realize that a lot of operations that I learned to do with data sets can also be done using **proc** sql statements, including merging, creating variables, subsetting and many others.

My question is therefore  : "When is it best to do what ?", is proc sql better ? always ? Which is the fastest, which is the less memory-consuming ?

Note that I probably anticipate that the answer is "it depends", in which case I would like to know on what.

Comment: While this is an interesting discussion topic, it's not a question with a particular answer and is too broad for this site.  http://communities.sas.com/ would be a better site to post this question (though I'd say it's not really answerable in any useful fashion anywhere).

Comment: I'll say it again: this is _not_ an appropriate question here.  Questions like this should be closed, not answered.  This is a topic for a discussion, and SO is explicitly not about discussions.  This is a better topic for a SGF paper, really, and far beyond this site's scope.

Comment: I'd argue that while not everything in the questions is answerable, certain parts of it definately ARE answerable, and likely to be of use to future readers.

Comment: Rob, it's not an on topic StackOverflow question for several reasons.  It almost models the perfect 'discussion' question, and it is certainly is far too broad for this. I'll find some meta.SO/SE examples when I have a sec for why this is a model question for closing.

Comment: @RobertPenridge This is basically a classic "Gorillas vs Sharks" question.  See [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254576/should-this-vs-question-have-been-closed-by-a-moderator) for example, or [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) by Jeff Atwood (co-creator of SO).  It shouldn't be asked or answered, because it asks to compare two effectively different things; while you _could_ answer it, and it could contain some useful information, it's not right for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Joe Fair point.  But I believe that this question allows us to address a very common question (and misconception) that almost every SAS user will have at some point (ie. performance of datastep vs proc sql). This particular question would be hard to ask in a more specific manner, so yes it is very broad, but it does give us the opportunity to educate people with the tools that they can use to test performance themselves.  As devils advocate, I could argue that 90% of the SAS questions on SO are too specific and unlikely to be of use to others as well but those slip under the radar every day.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Then write a SGF or RUG paper on the matter - that's a good topic for that sort of thing.  It's just not appropriate for _here_.

Comment: And some of the questions here are poor questions, but it's not generally specificity: there's nothing wrong with something that answers a very specific issue.  Most of the ones that are poor questions are "do my work for me" overly-broad, and I've at least tried to not answer the really bad examples of those, and close vote them; but with a whole two of us able to close vote (most days) that doesn't get very far.

Comment: I am not familiar at all with SE meta, but this question is not a "shark vs gorilla" question. 
It is about comparing two methods that can do the same thing. With a naive sorting and a quicksort algorithms there is an unambiguous answer. Since these sas methods are built on different approaches, it could have been that one is better.

Comment: @AnthonyMartin It's shark vs gorilla because you're not providing a specific, single case.  If you had a single thing you're doing with them, and want to know which approach is faster, that would be a valid question.  These are two entirely different tools that have strengths and weaknesses.  There cannot be a single unambiguous answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you do steps:

```
data temp_new;
set temp;
run;
```

and

```
proc sql;
create table temp_new as
select *
from temp;
quit;
```

You will see no difference. But there are a lot. I will cover only features functionality, what You can do with data step and what you can with proc sql.

Data step can:

- use loops;
- infile from file.
- loop through data with open,fetch,fetchobs statements.
- use putLog/put to output to log/file;
- control your data flow with first, last, retain statements. `_n_`, `_error_` and other variables.
- output to different tables in a single dataStep.
- output statement controls how many records are added to dataset.
- use hash in datastep.
- use arrays
- force stopping reading
- When merging/setting, there is no limit to the number of input data sets, other than memory. (in SAS 9.1 in SQL: The maximum number of tables that can be joined at one time is 32. I do not know if it has changed in later SAS versions)
- basically complex business logic is easier to incorporate with data step processing.

Proc sql can:

- use grouping and ordering;
- use inner sql's.
- set operations (union/outer union/intersect/except).
- do inner/outer joins without sorting data.
- use integrity constraints on insert/delete/update operations. ( I do not cover data step with modify/update statements).
- Access DBMS directly.

One more big difference is how data step and proc sql works with datasets.
Data step reads record sequentially to program data vector, then does some processing with it and outputs it to dataset. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001290590.htm

While proc sql puts everything in memory or utility file (if memory is not enough ) and does all the calculations and joins in memory. After that it writes all the data to dataset.

I basically use both of them. Proc sql is efficient when doing some operations, which requires insert, update or delete small portions of data. For example You want to add one record to a dataset which has 1KK records. In that situation You will not use data step (You can use proc append alternative) 
If I need many joins with big tables, I prefer to do this with data step merge /proc sort combinations or other techniques (like putting one dataset to array, using hash or using formats), because it is not so painful in time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is proc sql better ?

No - just different.

> Which is the fastest?

Neither - performing the same steps via SQL usually take about the same time as performing them via a datastep.  It is very unlikely that you would ever see a noticeable speed difference by changing a typical data step to a typical SQL query.

> which is the less memory-consuming?

They're probably about the same, to find out for sure, use `option fullstimer;` which will give you notes similar to the following in your log window:

```
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           10.69 seconds
      user cpu time       1.62 seconds
      system cpu time     0.06 seconds
      memory              958.25k
      OS Memory           16328.00k
      Timestamp           10/21/2014 08:35:26 AM
```

> When is it best to do what ?

Use the approach that makes the code the most readable by others, and maintainable.

The one thing I can think of that I *almost* always use `proc sql` for is when I need to merge (ie. join) multiple datasets together using different join conditions for each dataset.  The data step doesn't provide an easy way to do this in a single step, while it is quite straightforward in `proc sql`.

Comment: Knowing nothing about datastep.... what happens if you have two very large datasets, then when joined (intersect) as required, result in a very small dataset. If datastep needs to first pull over the two very large datasets surely it would be quicker to perform this action locally (in the database) and send a small dataset, rather than redundantly transferring two large datasets to be processed by datastep

Comment: again - it depends :-)  There are definitely speed differences between the two approaches, there are also features / limitations specific to both.  Another consideration is readability (if it takes longer to run but is easier to debug / maintain then that can be an appropriate tradeoff).  For small datasets I agree, the difference is negligible.

Comment: oh, and yes - pass through SQL is of course going to be more efficient!  But that isn't due to the 'way' it is processed, more 'where' it is processed..

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The issue that you are referring to is dependent on your data access method, and storage location, not on whether proc sql or a data step is being used.  If the data is in local SAS tables then SQL/datastep will be 'the same'.  If you are accessing data remotely through and ODBC libname or SQL passthrough connection, the performance results will depend on many things including whether you have the appropriate SAS/ACCESS module licensed or if you are using a generic ODBC connector, and possibly other things as well.  In this case, try both approaches and see which is faster.

Comment: So when the user asks "is proc sql better"? this proc SQL might not actually be run on a database, it might be run on a local dataset?

Answer (score 0):

### it depends!

on what you are trying to achieve.  Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, this question cannot be answered.  Remember that the SAS language has been growing for decades..  SAS works hard to ensure 'backwards compatibility' and so there is a lot of stuff which is there for legacy purposes.

For instance when something new comes along (like SQL), SAS doesn't stop supporting customers who run programs based on data step.

The SAS language exists separately from the SQL syntax, and again separate from other languages (such as DS2, C++ or JAVA), all of which can be embedded within SAS and can perform many of the same operations..

Comment: So you say that it depends, and your answer seem to say it does not depend that much, that data steps are rather a legacy, while proc sql are based on a more optimized dbms which is sql, built precisely to be more efficient. So ?

Comment: nooo!  It certainly does depend - a lot.  SQL / datastep perform similar tasks but in fundamentally different ways.  SQL is an ANSI standard whilst SAS is a proprietary language.  Whether one is more efficient than another depends very much on what EXACTLY you are trying to do / in what context etc.  They both have advantages / disadvantages, and a good SAS developer needs both in his / her box of tricks..  I'd recommend attending a SAS course or achieving Advanced SAS certification.  All will become clear..